# Simple way of using Fabric or Boto to ssh into an AWS instance and run Shell commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto, fabric

Hello I'm following [This Tutorial](http://cewing.github.io/training.codefellows/assignments/day12/fabric.html) on running shell commands with EC2 instances but I later tried [This Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501845/boto-execute-shell-command-on-ec2-instance) (the first answer).

It still doesn't work. First I got error 
    unexpected keyword argument keypath

Then error 
    'Reservation' object has no attribute dns_name

So now I'm really confused. I had the instance spooled up and I used the proper instance id as well.

If there is an intuitive way to run a shell command on an AWS instance, I'd like to know. I already have my account and keys setup and I've run shell commands through the CLI but I want to automate the process. Fabric is proving a challenge to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was actually a bug in the example code that I provided for the second method you mentioned.  I have corrected the example code but basically you need to change this:

```
# Find the instance object related to my instanceId
instance = conn.get_all_instances(['i-12345678'])[0]
```

to this:

```
# Find the instance object related to my instanceId
instance = conn.get_all_instances(['i-12345678'])[0].instances[0]
```

Thanks for finding the problem.  I'm surprised no one mentioned it before.

Comment: Authentication failed. Which is weird since I used the same key that I used to login. My credentials also worked when I tried to connect.

Comment: SSH authentication?  Can you show the actual error message?