# Logging into a AWS instance using boto3 library of python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am attempting to write a python code that would few of my manual steps in logging into the AWS platform.

In Ubuntu terminal , I used to write the command

```
ssh -A ec2-user@<ip-address>
```

and then again log into another instance using

```
ssh ec2-user@<ip.address>
```

Now I am looking at python code that would be able to automate this logging in process. I have written the following code till now.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

Comment: boto3 is an SDK used for interfacing with the AWS API, not for performing actions in the terminal or on instances.  Do you perhaps mean that you want to use boto3 to retrieve the IP addresses of EC2 instances based on some criteria?  You would then need to use another library, perhaps [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), to perform any sort of actions over SSH.

Comment: @Fishizzle - I would not need the IP address of the instance. I already have that. I just need to log into the instance and then perform some actions.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah You don't want to login, you want to perform actions. What actions?

Comment: @S.deMelo - I am a little new to AWS so my terminologies might be a bit here and there. I would like to run a python script as a action.

Comment: @KshitijMarwah Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/15503965/6919239 help?

Comment: @S.deMelo Heads up that the `cmdshell` function was removed from boto3.  The answer you linked to is specific to boto 2.  `cmdshell` was effectively just a wrapper around Paramiko anyway.

Comment: @Fishizzle OK, good to know!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways mostly to configure the boto3 library.

1. You need to configure it first on your system and use the same configuration everywhere. You can use [**AWS CLI**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html) for this by running `aws configure` on your terminal.
2. Set the environment variables and call the boto3 configuration via `process.env.ENV_KEY` and then use it like :

`client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=process.env.SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=process.env.SESSION_TOKEN,
)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have 's3' configured. I would like to work on the ec2 instance of AWS.

Comment: That was an example. You can edit the resource to anything from ec2, s3, sqs, etc. Answer Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform actions on a running instance, boto3 is not what you're looking for.  What you're asking about is more in the realm of what's called *configuration management*.

While you could write something yourself using an SSH library like [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/), you may want to look at a more purpose-built software package like [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).  It's built on-top of the aforementioned Paramiko, with added functionality tailored to running commands on remote servers. For a more full-featured, open source configuration management solution, I recommend looking into [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/).

AWS also has a native service for configuring EC2 instances called [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/).